# F# parallel design pattern

Tags: multithreading, asynchronous, parallel-processing, f#

I am trying to run some same task in parallel in a F# Console project.

The task is as follow

1. Dequeue a table name from a `ConcurrentQueue`(this queue contains the table names my program need to process)
2. Open a SqlDataReader for the table
3. Write each row in the SqlDataReader to a StreamWriter
4. Zip the file created by the StreamWriter
5. Repeat 1 - 4

So basically each task is a while loop (pose as a recursion) to contiunously process tables. And I would like to start 4 tasks in parallel, and another thing is I would like to stop execution with a user keystroke on the Console, say `Enter` key. But the execution should only be stopped if the current task has complete step 4.

I have tried the following

```
let rec DownloadHelper (cq:ConcurrentQueue<Table>) sqlConn = 
    let success, tb = cq.TryDequeue()
    if success then
        printfn "Processing %s %s" tb.DBName tb.TBName
        Table2CSV tb.DBName tb.TBName sqlConn
        DownloadHelper cq sqlConn

let DownloadTable (cq:ConcurrentQueue<Table>) connectionString=
    use con = new SqlConnection(connectionString)
    con.Open()
    DownloadHelper cq con

let asyncDownloadTask = async { return DownloadTable cq connectionString}
let asyncMultiDownload =
    asyncDownloadTask
    |> List.replicate 4
    |> Async.Parallel
asyncMultiDownload
|>Async.RunSynchronously
|>ignore
```

There are two problems with the above code,

1. It blockes the main thread, thus I dont know how to do the keystroke part
2. I am not sure how to stop execution gracefully.

My second try is as below to use CancellationToken,

```
let tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource()

let cq = PrepareJobs connectionString
let asyncDownloadTask = async {  DownloadTable cq connectionString}
let task = async {  
            asyncDownloadTask
            |> List.replicate 4
            |> Async.Parallel
            |>ignore}
let val1 = Async.Start(task, cancellationToken =tokenSource.Token)
Console.ReadLine() |> ignore
tokenSource.Cancel()
Console.ReadLine() |> ignore
0
```

But it seems I am not even able to start the task at all.

Comment: The function `DownloadHelper` is recursive, and, once started, only stops when the queue has been consumed. As written, there's no way to control that. Consider, instead, a design where you separate the looping from the work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are three problems with your code.

First, the `DownloadHelper` should do *one* table only.
By making it recursive, you are taking too much control and
inhibiting parallelism.

Second, simply placing an operation in an `async` expression does not
magically make it async. Unless the `DownloadTable` function itself
is async, the code will block until it is finished.

So when you run four downloads in parallel, once started, they will
*all* run to completion, regardless of the cancellation token.

Thirdly, in your second example you use `Async.Parallel`
but then throw the output away, which is why your `task` does nothing!
I think what you wanted to do was throw away the *result* of the async, not the async itself.

Here's my version of your code, to demonstrate these points.

First, a dummy function that takes up time:

```
let longAtomicOperation milliSecs = 
    let sw = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch()
    let r = System.Random()
    let mutable total = 0.0
    sw.Start()
    while sw.ElapsedMilliseconds < int64 milliSecs do
        total <- total + sin (r.NextDouble())
    // return something
    total

// test
#time
longAtomicOperation 2000
#time
// Real: 00:00:02.000, CPU: 00:00:02.000, GC gen0: 0, gen1: 0, gen2: 0
```

Note that this function is not async -- once started it will run to completion.

Now let's put it an an `async`:

```
let asyncTask id = async {  
    // note that NONE of the operations are async
    printfn "Started %i" id
    let result = longAtomicOperation 5000 // 5 seconds
    printfn "Finished %i" id
    return result
    }
```

None of the operations in the async block are async, so we are not getting
any benefit.

Here's the code to create four tasks in parallel:

```
let fourParallelTasks = async {
    let! results = 
        List.init 4 asyncTask
        |> Async.Parallel
    // ignore
    return ()
    }
```

The result of the `Async.Parallel` is not ignored, but is assigned to a value,
which forces the tasks to be run. The `async` expression as a whole returns unit though.

If we test it:

```
open System.Threading

// start the task
let tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource()
do Async.Start(fourParallelTasks, cancellationToken = tokenSource.Token)

// wait for a keystroke
System.Console.WriteLine("press a key to cancel")
System.Console.ReadLine() |> ignore
tokenSource.Cancel()
System.Console.ReadLine() |> ignore
```

We get output that looks like this, even if a key is pressed,
because once started, each task will run to completion:

```
press a key to cancel
Started 3
Started 1
Started 2
Started 0
Finished 1
Finished 3
Finished 2
Finished 0
```

On the other hand, if we create a serial version, like this:

```
let fourSerialTasks = async {
    let! result1 = asyncTask 1
    let! result2 = asyncTask 2
    let! result3 = asyncTask 3
    let! result4 = asyncTask 4
    // ignore
    return ()
    }
```

Then, even though the tasks are atomic, the cancellation token is tested between
each step, which allows cancellation of the subsequence tasks.

```
// start the task
let tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource()
do Async.Start(fourSerialTasks, cancellationToken = tokenSource.Token)

// wait for a keystroke
System.Console.WriteLine("press a key to cancel")
System.Console.ReadLine() |> ignore
tokenSource.Cancel()
System.Console.ReadLine() |> ignore
```

The above code can be cancelled between each step when a key is pressed.

To process all elements of the queue this way in batches of four,
just convert the parallel version into a loop:

```
let rec processQueueAsync() = async {
    let! result = processFourElementsAsync()
    if result <> QueueEmpty then
        do! processQueueAsync()
    // ignore
    return ()
    }
```

Finally, to me, using async is *not* about running things in parallel so much
as it is to write non-blocking code.  So if your library code is blocking, the async
approach is not going to provide too much benefit.

To ensure your code is non-blocking, you need to using the async versions of `SqlDataReader` methods
in your helper, such as `NextResultAsync`.

Comment: Hi, the part where you created four task  let fourParallelTasks = async {
    let! results = 
        List.init 4 asyncTask
        |> Async.Parallel
    // ignore
    return ()
    }  when this is run, is this blocking?

Comment: It's running on a background thread, so no, it is not blocking the foreground thread or console.  My test function is unrealistic, as it is just chewing through CPU time. A *real* function that was doing I/O and blocking would be wasting resources (preventing other threads from running in the thread pool), and so that's why I recommend using the async versions of library calls.